# Manual for RedHat Linux (RHEL) Terminal Commands

Tags: linux, terminal, yum, rhel5

I've just got my first dev-box at work. We install linux ubuntu and then run RHEL via virtual box on these systems. I know a bit of linux commands, but I've totally lost touch. Is there any guide to the terminal commands in RHEL - when it comes to installing packages and port forwarding and so forth?

Something like a book for dummies....Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `man` pages which are installed like `man command_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fill all of your RedHat documentation needs here:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/

Maybe this one is the most relevant to your needs:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/System_Administrators_Guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks a Mill - I'm pretty we're using version 5 or something. Would the equivalent of the above document for v5 be [this](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/index.html). Thanks again.

Comment: Here are the links to version 5 docs: [link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/)   and yes, the link you gave does look to be the relevant RHEL 5 doc you want.  I see that it covers command line yum, which is  package management solution you are looking for.